# Python SQLite3 - fetch is not working on my code

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, sqlite

First time here!

I'm now stuck with python - databases realationship. I'm currently using sqlite3 to do so. So let's get to it: I have a server and a client, and I'm trying to authenticate the login process. Server receives a json 'list' with the username and password, then I do the standard Select * from db where . I use the same procedure to do the Sign Up part, which is working fine.
This is the Server part:

```
def autenticar_jogador():
    global data1   
    player_user = data1[1]
    player_passwd = data1[2]
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM cadastrohangman WHERE login = ? AND senha = ?', (player_user, player_passwd))
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    if results:
        conn.sendall('autenticado')
        print("Autenticado!")
    else:
        conn.sendall('Ops')
        print("Falha na autenticação")
```

This is the client part:

```
def autenticar():
    print("Autenticando...")
    lista_autenticar = ["autenticar", user.get(), passwd.get()]
    data_autenticar = json.dumps(lista_autenticar)
    print(data_autenticar)
    s.sendall(data_autenticar.encode())
    data2 = s.recv(1024)
    print(data2)
    if (data2 == 'autenticado'):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Nice!", "Login Efetuado!")
    elif (data2 == 'Ops'):
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Ops!","Tente novamente!")
```

At this stage, I'm certain that the client is actually receiving the data2 , but all the tries are returning the showerror , so I don't know if the cursor.execute can't find the login and password from the database OR if I'd messed up some part (like that line 8 from server part... I know that sucks heh)

Thanks in advance for any incoming help. Cya!

Comment: Not an answer, but you should not be storing clear text passwords in your SQLite user table.  Hash the password, and then store it.

Comment: Hey, Iagom! Thanks for the answer! This is actually for an essay for one of my college classes, so no worries for security issues.

Comment: Print out the username and password parameters on the server side, and check them to make sure they are right.  Then, try running some test query on the server side, with username and password hard coded.  All of this should be working.

Comment: Nice! I did it. I can see that the server is actually receiving everything ok (I guess it's OK, it's coming like [u'user', u'password'], but I believe that is not the source of my problem.